# Python parser to extract keyvalue pair from a output

Tags: python, parsing, text

I have just started with python and am posed with extracting data from a text output. The text output is in forms of a text blocks and has key value pairs

```
status active
name server01
read:bytes 4096
user abcd-12345-def
drive hgbcv-76s7e-hwte7ehxd-22byt82h
write:bytes 4096
read:requests 1
type disk
write:requests 1
size 1099511627776
```

```
status active
name server02
read:bytes 4096
user abcd-12345-def
drive ngcdha6-76eg-78q7dg73-76eydh
write:bytes 4096
read:requests 1
type disk
write:requests 1
size 1099511627776
```

I need to get each block parsed and display output as just

```
status,name,drive,type,disk
```

so for the above example, I should be able to get the output as

```
active,server01,hgbcv-76s7e-hwte7ehxd-22byt82h,disk,1099511627776
active,server02,ngcdha6-76eg-78q7dg73-76eydh,disk,1099511627776
```

Any help or pointer to achieve this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: So was this useful to you? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

This is approximately what you want:

```
def create_dict(lines):
    return dict(line.split(" ") for line in lines)

lines1 = [
    "status active",
    "name server01",
    "read:bytes 4096",
    "user abcd-12345-def",
    "drive hgbcv-76s7e-hwte7ehxd-22byt82h",
    "write:bytes 4096",
    "read:requests 1",
    "type disk",
    "write:requests 1",
    "size 1099511627776",
]
lines2 = [
    "status active",
    "name server02",
    "read:bytes 4096",
    "user abcd-12345-def",
    "drive ngcdha6-76eg-78q7dg73-76eydh",
    "write:bytes 4096",
    "read:requests 1",
    "type disk",
    "write:requests 1",
    "size 1099511627776",
]

d1 = create_dict(lines1)
d2 = create_dict(lines2)

keys = ("status","name","drive","type","size")
for d in (d1, d2):
    print ",".join(d[key] for key in keys)
```

This is the output I get:

```
>>> for d in (d1, d2):
...     print ",".join(d[key] for key in keys)
... 
active,server01,hgbcv-76s7e-hwte7ehxd-22byt82h,disk,1099511627776
active,server02,ngcdha6-76eg-78q7dg73-76eydh,disk,1099511627776
```

You need to figure out a way to put the related lines together for a call to `create_dict` and then you can filter on the keys you want.

Note that your key 'disk' should be 'size'.